# CONFIG += c++11 (still) doesn't work on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qmake

I've read several discussion on the topic, some saying that qmake < 3.0 doesn't support the directive correctly. I've just reinstalled Qt 5.9.1 for g++-64, but the problem is still there. Also, I've tried playing with various mkspecs/xxx/xxx.conf files with no luck.

Adding `CONFIG += c++11` to a .pro doesn't really add the CXX flag -std=c++11 in the Makefile, so one get the error

```
error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

when compiling.

I'm working on Linux x64 (an Ubuntu distro), with the last version of Qt libraries (5.9.1). Same project compiles with no errors on Windows with MSVC2015 and MinGw.

It works if I declare `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` instead of `CONFIG += c++11`, but it is suggested to use the former declaration, since qmake will automatically deal with CXX flags via CONFIG directive. Awfully, looks like it's not doing so...

Comment: Doesn't it have something to do with your GCC version ? Maybe your ubuntu is too old to use C++11

Comment: Can you try `qmake-qt5` rather than `qmake`?

Comment: @Xatyrian the g++ version is ok, since declaring `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` works

Comment: @G.M. qmake is actually linked to qt5 folder. Even using the one in the Qt 5.9.1 folder (qmake version 3.1) will give the same result. I have qmae-qt4 installed, but I don't know how to install/use qmake-qt5...

Answer (score 3):

`CONFIG += c++11` should be enough so that your compiler is called with the proper flags to enable C++11 support.

However, since 5.7, Qt requires C++11 support so even without `CONFIG += c++11` you should get your compiler called with C++11 support.

What I think is that for your compiler, qmake "thinks" c++11 support is the default behavior and qmake doesn't add the `-std=c++11` flag.

If you are curious you can check the mkspecs files. As @Swift mentioned you have to check yours as they might have been corrected. In the ones i have in my Qt install, it seems that all is ok as in `mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf`I have `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=c++11` and 
`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_GNUCXX11 = -std=gnu++11`.

If I am right that means that you could bypass qmake behavior by trying to use `CONFIG += c++14` (or `CONFIG += c++1z`). You could also try `CONFIG += strict_c++` (or `CONFIG -= strict_c++`), this option will disable (or enable) GNU extensions and thus force qmake to add `-std=c++11` (so that g++ will not use the implicit `-std=gnu++11`).

Answer (score 0):

CONFIG variable is meant to configure Qt code ( headers, may be metacode), so c++11 in it should be added to support c++11.  Compiler flag is a separate item, and may be required  or may not be requred depending on compiler and its version, newer  gcc defaults to gnu version of standard ( with extensions), e.g gcc 6.0 - to gnu++14.

Comment: For what I've understood, such CONFIG will be translated in a flag. As you said, "if needed". With MSVC2015, `CONFIG += c++11` does nothing, while `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` adds an useless flag (actually, a wrong flag, since I get a warning "ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'"). Anyway, as said, adding `CONFIG += c++11` directive doesn't actually add support for c++11 on linux-g++

Comment: @il_max QMAKE_CXXFLAGS is what literally is added to compiler's command line verbatim, CONFIG affects only internal preprocessor directives used in Qt code and what modules are linked, if i recall right. vc2015 still does not support c++11 fully!!!

Comment: Well, MSVC2015 partial support still supports what I need of c++11, so I'm ok with it. The problem is that qmake under Linux is giving me an headache to enable the c++11 support of g++

Comment: just putline `unix:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11` into .pro file and do not bother about that

Comment: Well, yes, it's what I'm doing right now. Was hoping to actually have the "magic" done automatically by qmake, as stated in various threads.

Comment: @il_max some distros had qt-dev distrbuted with corrected makespec.  i thnk, gcc 6.0 would take your code without that flag. Prior version required it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was my fault (obviously...)

As said, I've installed last version of Qt (5.9.1) via unified installer script. Still, my QtCreator was using as default an old kit with Qt4 (!!), installed via package manager who-remembers-when, so it was actually using an old version of qmake that doesn't deal with CONFIG directive. Forcing qtchooser to use qt5 doesn't modify the tools set in the used kit (learned something!). Using the last kit everything works as expected. Using qmake via command line, after setting qtchooser to use qt5, works as expected, too; I just wasn't looking for the correct Makefile (....).

So, I can confirm that the problem was the qmake version, as said in others threads.